# Getting error while trying to install react-native-image-picker using command line

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting the error below:

`npm install react-native-image-picker`

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-navigation-tabs@2.11.2
npm ERR! Found: react-native-gesture-handler@2.9.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler
npm ERR!   peer react-native-gesture-handler@"*" from react-native-tab-view@2.16.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-tab-view
npm ERR!     react-native-tab-view@"^2.15.2" from react-navigation-tabs@2.11.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-navigation-tabs
npm ERR!       react-navigation-tabs@"^2.11.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native-gesture-handler@">= 1.5.0" from react-navigation-stack@2.10.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-navigation-stack
npm ERR!     react-navigation-stack@"^2.10.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-gesture-handler@"^1.0.0" from react-navigation-tabs@2.11.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-navigation-tabs
npm ERR!   react-navigation-tabs@"^2.11.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-gesture-handler@1.10.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler
npm ERR!   peer react-native-gesture-handler@"^1.0.0" from react-navigation-tabs@2.11.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-navigation-tabs
npm ERR!     react-navigation-tabs@"^2.11.2" from the root project
I tried updating mentioned modules but nothing happened. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using two incompatible libraries. To be more exact, you may be using one that is outdated.

The issue at least lies between these two lines:

```
npm ERR! Found: react-native-gesture-handler@2.9.0
```

and

```
npm ERR! peer react-native-gesture-handler@"^1.0.0" from react-navigation-tabs@2.11.2
```

Having `react-native-gesture-handler@"^1.0.0` in a dependency means that the dependency resolution should only accept versions `1.x.x` and not `2.x.x` of the library.

Considering what your problem is right now, you may want to just remove in your `package.json` file the specific reference to `react-native-gesture-handler`, because my guess is that you installed it manually and it got resolved to the latest version.

**However**, if you want to make your solution future-proof, you may want to look on the internet for the right libraries. If you look on the official page of the `react-navigation-tabs` library [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-tabs), you will find that this library is not supported anymore, you have to use `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` now.
I strongly advise you do that for all your libraries before really digging into the project, because refactoring can be a huge hassle if done too late, since updates will probably involve stability and compatibility improvements, if not even security fixes.

I hope this will help.